# Facebook FQL Select Album by name

Tags: javascript, facebook, coffeescript, facebook-fql

Is is possible to get a users photos from a specific album by specifying its name? I'm trying to only get the album called "mobile uploads".

```
offset = 0
mobile = "mobile uploads"
mobileUploads = "SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE name=" + mobile + ") ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT " + offset + ",16"
$.getJSON "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" + mobileUploads.replace(/\s+/g, "+") + "&access_token=" + FB.getAccessToken(), (data) ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have a couple of errors in your FQL. Try this:

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN 
   (SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me() AND name="mobile uploads") 
   ORDER BY created DESC
```

- `aid` != `album_object_id`
- You must specify an `owner` to make the subquery indexable.
- You could also use `type = 'mobile'` in case the user renamed their "Mobile Uploads" album or has multiple albums.

Comment: thanks! But I'm getting an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" from the name="mobile uploads" bit, so how would I put in the type=mobile. I tried to put it in the album part and got a response "TYPE is not a member of the album table". That was just by replacing name="mobile uploads" to type=mobile..

Comment: Sorry. You need quotes around `mobile` since it's a string. I corrected my answer above.